# How can I alter a Delphi destructor to handle shared object instances?

Tags: delphi, soap, destructor

How can I alter my destructors to handle shared object instances?

Example:

```
type
    TAddress = class
    private
        FStreet : String;
    public
    property street: String read FStreet write FStreet;
    end;

    TContract = class
    private
        FAddress : TAddress;
    public
    property address: TAddress read FAddress write FAddress;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    end;

    Array_Of_TContract = array of TContract;

    TCustomer = class
    private
      FContracts : Array_Of_TContract;
    public
    property contracts: Array_Of_TContract read FContracts write FContracts;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    end;

implementation

    destructor TCustomer.Destroy;
    var
      I: Integer;
    begin
      for I := 0 to System.Length(FContracts)-1 do
        SysUtils.FreeAndNil(FContracts[I]);
      System.SetLength(FContracts, 0);
      inherited Destroy;
    end;

    destructor TContract.Destroy;
    var
      I: Integer;
    begin
        SysUtils.FreeAndNil(FAddress);
      inherited Destroy;
    end;

begin
  Try
    //address
    myAddress := TAddress.Create;
    myAddress.street := 'My Street';

    //First contract
    SetLength(myContracts, Length(myContracts)+1);
    FirstContract := TContract.Create;
    FirstContract.address := myAddress;   //<-
    myContracts[0] := FirstContract;

    //Second contract
    SetLength(myContracts, Length(myContracts)+1);
    SecondContract := TContract.Create;
    SecondContract.address := myAddress;  //<-
    myContracts[1] := SecondContract;

    //Single customer
    myCustomer := TCustomer.Create;
    myCustomer.contracts := myContracts;

    myCustomer.Free;

    self.Close;
  Except
    On e: exception do begin
      ShowMessage(e.Message);
    end;
  End;

end;
```

The result is an invalid pointer operation when freeing myCustomer (and memory leak).

(Creating a separate TAddress object for each TContract is not an option in my case)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this kind of situation depends on the structure of your application. Based on the example I would add all the adresses to a generic objectlist and then pass the address reference to the instance of `TContract`. For contracts you could use similar approach if they aren't unique.
Alternative is to use interface for the address and then just assign it to the contract instance and finally nil it.
The third option is to copy on assignment. I think that this is the most inefficient way to handle this situation but it's quaranteed to work in every situation.
Hopefully these gave some ideas.

Comment: Personally prefer the interface option - it's effectively implementing reference counting and garbage collection for you

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer not to share the same address instance between contacts. But since code is auto-generated, I guess this is not an option.

You could keep track of already freed references:

```
AlreadyFreed := TList <Pointer>.Create;
for I := 0 to System.Length(FContracts)-1 do
  begin
  if not AlreadyFreed.Contains(FContracts[I]) then
    begin 
    FContracts[I].Free;
    AlreadyFreed.Add(Pointer(FContracts[I]));
    end;
  end;
```